# Hibernate - How to externalize schemas in a multiple schemas configuration?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, schema

I'm trying to find a way to externalize database schema definitions in Hibernate, in an external config file such as `application.properties`.
My domain objects are declared this way :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORIES", schema = "SCHEMA1")
public class Category { ....

@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS", schema = "SCHEMA2")
public class Group { ....
```

I would like to put the schemas in a config file so they can be changed without having to re-compile the application.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Edit: I'm using Java 8 with Spring Boot

Comment: flyway, https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, but I'm afraid this is not what I am looking for. I can't afford a database migration (even though this model is not easy to deal with)